# Cannot run program "pip --version" (in directory "."): error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I execute a simple Linux command through `aws emr`. This command is launched on the nodes of a cluster:

```
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id j-XXXXXXXXXX --steps Name="XXX",Jar="command-runner.jar",Args=["pip --version"]
```

or:

```
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id j-XXXXXXXXXX --steps Name="XXX",Jar="command-runner.jar",Args=["python --version"]
```

These basic commands give an error:

```
Cannot run program "pip --version" (in directory "."): error=2, No such file or directory

Cannot run program "python --version" (in directory "."): error=2, No such file or directory
```

I am sure that at least `python` is installed on the nodes, because I can execute `spark-submit` with `*.py` files.

The only command that I was able to execute was `ls`.

P.S. The objective of using this approach is to be able to execute some Linux scripts on different nodes of the cluster, e.g. `pip install ...`. That's why I started with making small experiments and was unable to make them working.

Comment: `pip` is not a built-in Linux command, it is an application that may not be installed or your Linux machine. Are you sure it is installed?

Comment: @UnholySheep: If `pip` is not installed, then I expect that the error message would be like `pip: command not found`. The problem is that the error is `Cannot run program "pip --version" (in directory ".")`. Similar error appears even for `cd /usr/`. Only `ls` runs without problems.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was due to the lack of comma `,` between the arguments. There should be `pip,--version` instead of `pip --version`:

```
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id j-XXXXXXXXXX --steps Name="XXX",Jar="command-runner.jar",Args=["pip,--version"]
```

Comment: Are you sure you got that right? `["pip, --version"]` is still a list with a single item.

Comment: @BryanOakley: The resonse that I get with the COPY-PASTE of my answer (putting the correct cluster ID) is `pip 6.1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)`. So, I wonder why you downvoted the answer.

Comment: @BryanOakley: By the way, look carefully at my answer. It does not have a space between the comma and `--version`. Your comment is meaningless.